# Difference between numpy.fromstring() and numpy.frombuffer()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried these two `numpy` array creation routines with the same input data :

```
with open('myfile.bin', 'rb') as f:
    a = f.read(array_length)
numpy.fromstring(a, dtype=numpy.int16)
numpy.frombuffer(a, dtype=numpy.int16)
```

and they both give the same result.

**Is there any difference between these two functions ?**

*If possible I would like not to copy `a` into a new place of the memory, I would prefer to assign `a` as a numpy array, without re-copying it.*

Comment: I do believe this is a duplicate, but in a nutshell, you want `frombuffer` if you want to avoid making a copy. The resulting array will be read-only in that case, though. (If I recall correctly, it might not have been in older versions of numpy. I remember being to abuse it to change the contents of numpy strings in-place at some earlier point.)